# MySQL database activity log: fields vs table

Tags: mysql, database, logging, database-schema

So basically I am in the process of creating a personal finance tracking system.  It occurred to be that keeping tabs on when each instance and transaction was last edited or updated might be of relevant information some day.

Now as far as I can see there are two approaches to implement something like this:

1. Create "updated" fields to all the tables  I want to keep track of and then let mysql update those fields for me (ON UPDATE clause)
2. Create a completely seperate table for holding the log data and then update that with a triggers and transactions

Now it seems that 1st approach would have the benefit of keeping things simple and easy to maintain.  However how this will impact the performance if I suddenly decide to get every log in the database for review.  Also this would kind of goes against normalization (not by much though) with same data stored in multiple tables.

The second approach would allow more flexibility to the logging system and might actually shorten the sql query necessary to retrieve certain data.  However it would make the schema more complex as two additional tables would have to be created (the actual log table and many-to-many relation table for holding the keys) and maintained.  On the other hand if I ever want to implement an activity history this approach would propably be the only one capable of doing it.

As such I would like to know some more pros and cons to each method.  Since 2nd option allows more flexibility I am considering implementing it but I am not sure about performance issues.  In the end it comes down to two guestions:

> Are there any real life examples where both approaches are
>   implemented?

And:

> Are there any studies, comparisons or other resource that might shed
>   some light  on which is considered more performance friendly and "best
>   practices" approach?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what kind of reporting you need and your current architecture.

If you just want to know last update date, then having 2 fields (creation date and last update) should be enough. That's because having separate table won't give any perfomance boost, but will make your code harder to maintain.

It's another story if you want to have something more elaborate, like reporting differences (what was changed) and/or have full change log on each transaction (there might be few updates to one transaction, right?). In this case you actually must have separate table, because otherwise it will bloat your table and reduce perfomance.

Based on my experience, I'd go with separate table. That's because it will be easier to maintain - your logging logic will be practically separated from everything else and I think one day you'll need that additional info on your transactions and full transaction history.

As far as perfomance goes, you won't notice any formidable difference unless your system will be under serious load. But as your system is personal, any choice would suffice, just don't forget about proper indexing.

Note that I'm making alot of assumptions here, so if you want something more specific, please provide your actual architecture and reporting needs. I'd suggest some books on high availability/perfomance, but they are not on your specific needs, but on general availability/perfomance.

Comment: You are making a lot of right assumptions.  How would you implement this in terms of schema?  Would you set a foreign key to all tables for the logging table (to allow simpler SELECT queries) or would you just leave the table as completely seperate entity?

Comment: I'd suggest 2 ways: 1) Have 2 ID fields (GUID for example), one global same for all transactions in an operation and another one - unique per each transaction. This way you won't actually need any logging (assuming you don't need any additional log data), but querying statistics will be slower, because you'd need to aggregate every operation to get final results. 2) Simpler way. Store your data as row per operation and update it. In this case I'd use simple autoincrement as key for separate log table and store any changes there. Specifics depends on your actual needs.